# ODE solutions - how un-differentiable can they be?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, continuity, fractals

Suppose we have a first order Ordinary Differential Equation, $y^\prime(x)=f(x,y)$.  On the face of it, it *looks* as though any solution $y$ should be differentiable throughout its domain, but this may not be the case if the function has singular points.

The question linked here constructs a differentiable function whose derivative has a Cantor set of discontinuities: [Discontinuous derivative.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/292275/discontinuous-derivative) Thinking along these lines, is it possible to go further and build an "ODE solution" that, like the [Weierstrass function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_function), is continuous but (*[almost](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/WeierstrassFunction.html)* **?**) nowhere differentiable?

Notice that the *antiderivative* of the Weierstrass function is "fairly smooth", per [What does the antiderivative of a continuous-but-nowhere-differentiable function "look like"?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/829911/what-does-the-antiderivative-of-a-continuous-but-nowhere-differentiable-function), so while $y=\int W$ solves $y^\prime=W(x)$, such an ODE does not have the weird property I'm asking about.

However, I wonder if $W$ itself, despite not being differentiable, could in some degenerate sense be considered an ODE solution?

The example of $\int W$ would appear to give circumstantial evidence to support the idea that integration is a smoothing operation, and that a solution to an ODE should therefore be mostly smooth.  The only problem with that theory, of course, is that equations with *singular* solutions appear all over the place.

If any such bizarre functions could be constructed, are they forbidden on aesthetic or practical grounds in the theory of ODEs?

Comment: I think we are fine as long as the singular points form a set of measure zero. Short of that, we are in trouble, and it is about as bad as it looks.

Comment: What is your definition of *solution* to an ODE?

Comment: @Romeo not sure yet!  But, e.g., in this case perhaps it's relevant to work with the Laplace transform to generate a "weak solution".

Answer (score 2):

An ODE has at least one derivative expression in it. A function $f$ that is differentiable almost nowhere is going to be undefined in the ODE almost everywhere. So it isn't logically possible for an $f$ undefined almost everywhere in an equation to be a solution to said equation.

Comment: Logic does not always apply in mathematics in the way you would expect.  What is the sum of [1+2+3+4+...](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1_%2B_2_%2B_3_%2B_4_%2B_%E2%8B%AF#Ramanujan_summation) ?

Comment: “Sum” in that sense is not the same as the usual “sum” you’re thinking of. The series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty n$ indeed is divergent in the usual sense of the word sum.

Comment: I am similarly happy for "derivative" to be reinterpreted in the definition of ODEs.  Consider e.g. solutions in the sense of distributions.