# Evaluating $\mathrm{\int_0^1 ?(x)dx}$

Tags: definite-integrals, recreational-mathematics, continued-fractions, constants, non-smooth-analysis

This function interestingly shown as ?(x) is dubbed the [Minkowski Question Mark Function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/MinkowskisQuestionMarkFunction.html). It looks very similar to x. Wolfram Alpha can even plot the derivative of this apparently smooth function. Here are some details for what I want to find without using trivial solutions like the Riemann Sum definition nor $n^{th}$ derivatives in the answer from Taylor Series.$ \ a_k$ represents a [continued fraction](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction) of x=$[a_1,…,a_k]$ as seen in the first top link.

$$q=\int_0^1 ?(x)dx=-2\int_0^1\limits \sum_k \frac{(-1)^k}{2^{\sum_{n=1}^ka_n}}dk≈.5$$

This brings up the property of $$?(x^{-1})=\frac1{2^{x-1}}\implies ?(x)=2^{1-\frac1x}, x=k^n\mathop \implies ^? q\mathop =^?\int_0^1 2^{1-\frac1x}dx=2\ln(2)\mathrm{Ei}(-\ln(2))+1=.475050468…≈.5$$

Here is what the constant looks amazingly like: [image]

This result seems correct for a closed form with the [exponential integral function](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_integral):[image]

It would be very nice to find a non-integral form of this constant which is not a trivial solution like the one described in paragraph one. This function does not looks smooth, but that does not mean we cannot integrate it. What is a better, closed form or not, alternative representation or form for the area under Minkowski’s Question Mark function as defined over the unit interval $x\in$[0,1]? Please correct me and give me feedback!

Result over half period because of [self symmetry](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-similarity) which seems to fail for a result:

$$\int_0^\frac12 ?(x)dx+\frac1{2^2}+1-\int_0^\frac12?(x)dx=\int_0^1 ?(x)dx=\frac12$$

Comment: [$?(1-x)=1-{?}(x)$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski%27s_question-mark_function#Self-symmetry) immediately gives $\int_0^1 ?(x)\,dx=1/2$.

Comment: ?(x) is a singular continuous function. Its derivative is 0 a.e.  Approximations to the derivative are interesting.

Comment: @YuvalPeres Please see [this other integral of “fractal” function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4228961/evaluating-mathrm-int-limits-01-dx-dx-i-21-1-sum-limits-n-2-infty-f?noredirect=1&lq=1). Do you know if it is possible to find another definite or indefinite integral of $ ?(x)$ $\quad$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As metamorphy points out, we have $?(1-x) = 1 - ?(x)$, so:

$$\int_{0}^{1} ?(x) \text{d}x = \int_{0}^{1} 1-?(1-x) \text{d}x = 1 - \int_{0}^{1}?(1-x)\text{d}x = 1 + \int_{1}^{0}?(u)\text{d}u$$

where $u = 1-x$. If $I = \int_{0}^{1} ?(x)\text{d}x$, then $I = 1 - I$, and we have $I = \frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: I'm not understanding exactly what you mean. If $x=1$, this gives you the value of $?(x)$. Are you looking to get a general antiderivative of $?(x)$ ?

Comment: Yes, I have tried it out, and it seems that the same technique cannot be used as the integrals cannot be combined after substitution. I wonder if we can find a general anti derivative of “?(x)”. I saw [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/829911/what-does-the-antiderivative-of-a-continuous-but-nowhere-differentiable-function/829936#829936) post too.