# Evaluating $\mathrm{\int\limits_0^1 D(x) dx=I_2(1)-1-\sum\limits_{n=2}^\infty \frac{n\cos(n!)}{n!^2}}$. D(x) is the Darboux fractal function.

Tags: special-functions, bessel-functions, fractals, trigonometric-integrals, trigonometric-series

This question takes inspiration from

> [Evaluating $$\mathrm{\int_0^1 ?(x)dx}$$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4191367/evaluating-mathrm-int-01-xdx)

and other fractal questions.

Let me introduce the [**Darboux**](http://specialfunctionswiki.org/index.php/Darboux_function) function which has fractal properties due to being a continuos nowhere differentiable function. Here is the definition. Do not confuse the Darboux function with similar names.

$$\mathrm{Darboux(x)=D(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{sin((n+1)!x)}{n!}}$$

Here is the integral to be solved:

$$\mathrm{\int_0^1 D(x) dx=\int_0^1 \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{sin((n+1)!x)}{n!} dx= -\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{cos((n+1)!x)}{n!(n+1)!}\bigg|_0^1= -\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{cos((n+1)!x)}{(n+1)n!^2}\bigg|_0^1=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(n+1)!n!}-\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{cos((n+1)!)}{n!(n+1)!}= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1-cos((n+1)!)}{(n+1)n!^2}}$$

The evaluation at 0 term will remind you of a [Bessel function](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function) because of the factorial term squared in the denominator. So far our partial final answer is:

$$\mathrm{\int_0^1 D(x)dx=I_1(2)-1-\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{cos((n+1)!)}{(n+1)n!^2}= I_1(2)-1-\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{cos((n+1)!)}{n!(n+1)!}= I_1(2)-1-\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{cos(n!)}{Г(x)n!}= I_1(2)-1-\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{cos(n!)}{nΓ^2(n)}= I_1(2)-1- Re\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{e^ {i\,n!}}{nΓ^2(n)}= I_1(2)-1- Re\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{e^ {i\,n!}}{Γ(n)n!}= .71547…}$$

Finally, here is an [**interactive graph of the Darboux function**](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/n0bzcbboxo) and a beautiful visual representation of the constant: [image]

Here is a possible way to see a connection between the results:

$$\mathrm{D(1)=Im\sum_1^\infty\frac{e^{i (n+1)!}}{n!}}$$

while our goal integral and sum is:

$$\mathrm{\int_0^1 D(x) dx=I_2(1)-1-Re\sum_2^\infty\frac{ne^{i n!}}{n!^2}}$$

How do I evaluate the aforementioned cosine and factorial series? It seems to part of a more general Darboux function, but I cannot find much on it. I already have sum and integral representations, so now I need a better form *as a closed form seems impossible using known functions*. If there is a closed form, then it may be in terms of the D(x) Darboux function. A better form is one that written in exact form and possibly uses new functions, but it equal to our goal problem. Please correct me and give me feedback!