# How to graph the antiderivative of Weierstrass function: $f(x)= \sum\limits_{k=0}^ \infty \frac{\cos\left(13^k\pi x \right)}{2^k}$.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, graphing-functions

The  Weierstrass function:  $f(x)= \sum\limits_{k=0}^ \infty a^k {\cos\left(b^k\pi x \right)}$ where $0<a<1, \ b \in 2\mathbb{N}-1, \ ab > 1+\frac{3\pi}{2}$ is an example of a continuous function that has a derivative at no point.

Let  $f(x):= \sum\limits_{k=0}^ \infty \frac{\cos\left(13^k\pi x \right)}{2^k}$  is a Weierstrass function and it is contentious so it had an an antiderivative i.e $F(x):=\int_0^x f(t)dt$

I am curious how the graph of this $F$ looks like because $F(x)$ is differentiable at all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ but it doesn't have a second  derivative at any point.

I don't know how to graph such functions or what tools to use.

Comment: I would start by explicitly integrating it to get sine and then using Mathematica to graph  the series up to some large number N. https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Series.html

Comment: @ThomasKojar I don'y know what "Mathematica" is.

Comment: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Series.html

Comment: It would look like [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/829911/what-does-the-antiderivative-of-a-continuous-but-nowhere-differentiable-function/829936#829936)

Comment: @pie Wolfram Mathematica is a software system with built-in libraries for several areas of technical computing that allow machine learning, statistics, symbolic computation, data manipulation, network analysis, time series analysis, NLP, optimization, plotting functions and various types of data, implementation of algorithms, creation of user interfaces, and interfacing with programs written in other programming languages.

Comment: @Gary This seem to be a very useful thing to learn, How can I start learning to use Mathematica, as you can see I have no idea about Mathematica  at all or any   programming languages or any math software I might ask on MSE about this but I think this type of questions will attract down votes and will not get any answer because I have no idea about  this

Comment: @pie  There are documentations online. There is also mathematica.stackexchange.com where you can ask questions. You can also try https://www.wolframalpha.com/

Comment: @Gary I have some questions: can you give some of these documentations? Is wolfram alpha is the same as Mathematica ? if not how to use Mathematica ? do i need to install some app or it is on some website ?

Comment: Related: [Who first drew the Weierstrass function?](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/q/3058/264)